# How can I reference bound data within a ng-click attribute?

Tags: angularjs

It's been a long day, and I am likely missing something obvious but. . .

I have a `ng-repeat` list of radio buttons that reflects live UPS shipping rates to a customer's location (e.g. "Overnight", "2 day", etc).

Here is the markup:

```
 <div ng-repeat="i in ShippingRates">
      <div class='radio'>
              <label>
                 <input value="{{i.Rate}}" ng-model="Cart.ShippingCharge" type="radio" name="shipping-method" ng-click="SetSelectedMethod('Other')" />{{i.ShippingMethod}} <span ng-if="i.Rate > 0">({{i.Rate | currency}})</span></label></div>
 </div>
```

I already have the `ng-model` of the radio button associated with `i.Rate` returned from UPS (e.g. $100).

Now, I *additionally* need to store the `text` of the radio button as the "SelectedShippingMethod".  I thought the way to do this might be to add a `ng-click` like this:

```
 <input value="{{i.Rate}}" ng-model="Cart.ShippingCharge" type="radio" name="shipping-method" ng-click="SetSelectedMethod('{{i.ShippingMethod}}')" />
```

And then the function would be something like:

```
$scope.SetSelectedMethod = function(method){
    $scope.SelectedShippingMethod = method;
}
```

But this does not work as it results in `$scope.SelectedShippingMethod` literally getting set to `"{{i.ShippingMethod}}"`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function inside the ng-click is already a JavaScript method, not an HTML snippet, so you don't have to evaluate the variable as an expression.  Simply call the variable.

e.g. `ng-click="SetSelectedMethod(i.ShippingMethod)"`

Comment: Well I'm embarrassed.  Can you hear the sound of me smacking my forehead?  I can accept the answer in 5 minutes.  Thanks!